# Complementing Ogre3D and C++

Tags: c++, ogre

I will start my first 3D game, and for now I'm inclined to Ogre3D and C++. But Ogre3D isn't an engine. It is a 3D rendering library, and quoting another user here in GameDev: *Ogre3D does not have integrated **collision**, **physics**, **networking**, **sound**, **scripting**, etc.*

My question is, what the solutions for that "missing features"? Is there some good free/oss libraries to make that parts?

Comment: What technology to use questions are off topic for the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask here.

Comment: @Byte56 huh? Here isn't a right place to ask about a colision library for game development, by example?

Comment: Nope, see the FAQ and specifically [this question](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good) on meta. Since there's no *correct* answer to "which X should I use".

Comment: Byte56 is correct. Feel free to come discuss this in [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), or on another discussion-oriented site (gamedev.net forums, Reddit, etc.). Or search Google. The answer to your second question is "yes". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked [gamekit](http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/)? Not the irrlitch version (deprecated) but the ogre3d one, also known as ogrekit.

It's a whole set of libraries that cover most of the aspects of a game engine. Code is super clean (imho), project setup is awesome (imho) and as a bonus it works out of the box on several platforms.

Best part, you can cut off what you don't need or replace it.

Comment: Answering questions that are off topic promotes people asking those questions anyway. Thus diminishing the usefulness of the site.

Comment: You're right and it's nice that you comment it but I think that it was one of this situations when "bending the rules" a bit, even when offtopic, may point the guy in the right direction. My apologies tho.

Comment: You can invite them to chat and tell them your answer there. That's perfectly reasonable without "bending the rules".